# SQL Server: 2005 instance running, need 2008 instance to run instead

Tags: sql-server

I have both SQL Server 2005 and 2008 installed on my machine. Only the 2005 instance is being detected as running (via Windows apps, like Management Studio and LightSwitch). How do I change the running instance to the 2008 version?

Comment: In your Windows services, just stop the 2005 instance service, and start the 2008 instead. Also: if you have two instances, one of them must have an **instance name** by which you can access it, e.g. `(local)\2008` or something - you picked that when you installed the SQL Server on your machine

Comment: You can run both side-by-side if you want also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your default instance is 2005.  Your 2008 instance must be named instance:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531.aspx

You can connect to a named instance using the server\instance notation

http://www.compiledthoughts.com/2009/04/understanding-ms-sql-server-named.html

Comment: I ended up uninstalling some kind of partial installation of 2008 and did a full installation of 2008 Developer with a new named instance. That did the trick.